# Picklingtools requirements on python version

Tags: python, pickle

I tried using [Picklingtools](http://www.picklingtools.com/home) with my python 3.5.2 installation and I got a lot of syntax error. It appear this was due to the fact that the code was not written for 3.5.2. But impossible to find online the supported versions of python. Anyone knows for which versions of python this lib is intended to?

Comment: Could you please provide some of the syntax errors you see? If it is a large list, try using pastebin.com and sharing the link with us.

Comment: Also, they have an email on their contact page: http://www.picklingtools.com/about_us

Comment: I'll send them a quick message. For exemple, in midastalker.py, line 143 :
raise socket.timeout, "open time out"

                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Old form of raise is not supported in Python 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From their [FAQ](http://www.picklingtools.com/html/faq.html):

> What versions of Python does PicklingTools support?
>
> Historically, versions 2.1.x to 2.6.x have been tested extensively.
>   More recently, 2.7 has been tested and should work, but it has not
>   been tested as much as the other versions.
>
> 3.x has not been tested: We are waiting for our main paying customer to adopt the 3.x series.